# Как правильно сформировать запрос для PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser?

Tags: php, html, парсер

Как правильно сформировать запрос для PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser ?

**Дан код**, он из Feed вконтакта:

`<h5 class="post_author"><a class="author" href="/kopter_86" data-from-id="7871209" data-post-id="7871209_3485">Назар Добровський</a> <span class="explain">поделился ссылкой</span></h5>`

**Задача**: Спарсить все значения (цифры) data-from-id="7871209"
на выходе должен получиться результат:
7871209,
4134142,
и тд.

**Сначала как правило подключаем класс и файл**

include('simple_html_dom.php');
 $html = file_get_html('test.html');

а дальше я уже не понял, помогите

Comment: Во-первых , разместите код в вопрос - там внизу есть "править" . Во-вторых, я например не понял, что вы хотите. Напишите лучше желаемый результат.

Comment: поправил, прописал результат

Comment: А вы именно PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser хотите или DomDocument устроит ?

Comment: любой вариант устроит, главное чтобы работало

Comment: Выводит 0, в двух случаях

Answer (score 1):

```
// ищем `a` c атрибутом `data-from-id`
foreach($html->find('a[data-from-id]') as $a) 
// выводим. в фигурных скобках с кавычками, потому что имя с дефисами
    echo $a->{'data-from-id'} . "\n";
```

Comment: Выводит 1 результат, а их множестро в коде

Comment: так foreach по результатам find сделайте

Comment: Спасибо большое  splash58, вы решили мой вопрос который растянулся на двое суток очень быстро)

Comment: поменял на другой test.html стало выбивать Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался с ошибкой  Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Необходимо в simple_html_dom.php define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 600000), изменить, чтобы подгружало файлы большего размера